# Android read NFC tag data

Tags: java, android, nfc, rfid

I am currently developing an app which will read `NFC tags` currently i have written  the code to get `TAG id` what should i do next? How can i read all data if the `intent` extra named`EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES` is empty.

the code for reading RFID i have for now is

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        String zin =  tag.getTechList()[0];
        info.setText("TagID: " + bytesToHex(tag.getId())+" Saturs: "+zin);    

 }
```

I would like to know how to read all data in that `NFC tag`.

Thank you allready!

Comment: I am confused, do you read RFID or NFC tags?

Comment: @Thomas sorry about that, i want to read RFID.

Comment: So why are you using the NfcAdapter? (Like in NFC != RFID)

Comment: @Thomas there are lots similar app's that reads RFID cards using integrated phones NFC adapter! one of them is called e-talons reader and it works almost correctly...... i want to build something like that using the same tech.

Comment: In that case, do you have some links for those apps?

Comment: @Thomas [e-talons reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.janhouse.nfc.apis.mifare&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5qYW5ob3VzZS5uZmMuYXBpcy5taWZhcmUiXQ..) reads `Mifare Rfid cards` [NFClasic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pocketluxus.nfclassic&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5wb2NrZXRsdXh1cy5uZmNsYXNzaWMiXQ..) reads `NFC` and `RFID` and both of them are using `NfcAdapter Class` to read them!

Comment: Where is the documentation? Because neither of those apps list RFID on their page.

Comment: @Thomas Ok! maybe i am wrong, bu you could at least tell me how to read all data from that `NFC` tag if `ndef_messages` are empty

Comment: Edit your question and tell us what you already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your TAG's type. An example for an ultralight mifare

```
Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
MifareUltralight uTag = MifareUltralight.get(tagFromIntent);
uTag.connect(); //You should enclose this into a try-catch because of probably IOException
byte[] data = uTag.readPages(INDEX_OF_PAGES_YOU_WANT); //This returns 4 consecutive pages from the offset you declared. Each page weights 4 bytes
uTag.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! that just did the what i needed :D